# Software that can be used it import image files and exclude duplicates

Tags: images

Does anybody know of a software package that i can use to import image files, that during the import process will automatically detect and allow me to exclude duplicates.

I used this when taking photos i would import all the new ones from the SD card and leave the rest in place. I was using Picassa to do this but that option is no longer avilable

Other details

1. It needs to be able to handle over a TB of data in one import
2. It should be able to be pointed to a drive and exclude all the non image files.

Note for now i found a picasa installer here https://picasa.google.com.au/. Buts since the intention seems to ditch it I would like an alternative.

Comment: Although picasa is discontinued you might want to use it anyway.  Also picasa stores its data in a sqlite db which you should be able to extract the data from.  I continue to use it and it works just fine.